# Stop a continuous Ping

Tags: powershell, cmd, ping

I am trying to create Powershell script where
User will provide text file with ipaddress/ hostname and test Duration
•   Script should take each ip address/ Hostname, open cmd/ powershell and run ping test
For this I created a bat file containing

```
ping -t %1 |find /v ""|cmd /q /v:on /c "for /l %%a in (0) do (set "data="&set /p "data="&if defined data echo(!Date! !time! !data!)" > %2
```

In powershell I am running it
$Script = "C:\Ping\pingTest\pingstat.cmd $hostName $outputFile"
$Runpingtest = cmd.exe /c  $script

Please give me ideas to spot the contiguous ping as per test duration

Comment: If you are using PowerShell, use `Test-Connection`. The typical time for each ping is one (1) second. The `-Delay` parameter can change that. Use the command `help Test-Connection -Full` for more information.

Comment: The ping should have a propert such as `/n <count>` where counts specifies the number of echo Request messages sent. The default should be 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a continuous ping without signaling the ping process to stop. You would need to use `ping /n COUNT` for a number of pings.

---

But you can do something similar with pure PowerShell and [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps), then export the results to CSV like so:

```
1..$pingCount | Foreach-Object {
  Test-NetConnection google.com |
    Select-Object @{
      Name='Date'
      Expression={ Get-Date -Format 'ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ff' }
    }, ComputerName, SourceAddress, RemoteAddress, PingSucceeded,
    @{
      Name='Latency'
      Expression={ "$($_.PingReplyDetails.RoundTripTime) ms" }
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Path\To\file.csv
```

Note that `Test-NetConnection` doesn't have a `-Count` parameter, which is why the my above code wraps the `Test-NetConnection` call in a loop. You may also need to adjust the `Get-Date` format for your locale as my code uses a date formation suitable in the US.

Also note that I'm using `Select-Object` to create custom `Date` and `Latency` columns, as `Test-NetConnection` doesn't provide the current time it was run, and the ping latency is buried in a nested object.